# Wireshark only capturing broadcast packages

Tags: wifi, wireshark, tcpdump

I've ran Wireshark multiple times on my notebook for wireless networks verifying mobile packages for my devices and it used to work most of the time.

I haven't been able to monitor my traffic today on three different networks - my home router and two mobile wifi routers at home too.

Before I used to run Wireshark on my Fedora, put `wlan0` in monitor mode and get access to all network packages, filter TCP and do my work.

What I tried today is:

1. Run wlan0 in Wireshark in monitor mode - disconnecting after 30 seconds - reading a bit seems like this is normal, even though it used to work for me before.
2. Bring `ifconfig wlan0 down` and `airmon-ng start wlan0` which creates a `mon0` monitor
3. Try capturing packages from `mon0` or `wlan0`, both only in monitor mode or monitor + promiscuous mode together
4. I tried starting a monitor on a specific channel based on [other suggestions](https://superuser.com/a/744375) from experienced users, but doesn't seem to work.
5. I ran different monitors (up to `mon6`) with different configuration settings from Wireshark, but the output was the same.

In all instances I only get access to beacons, and no TCP packages or any other relevant network information that I need. And for confirmation, the WiFi card support monitoring since I've done that a dozen times before on the same machine.

I ruled out my personal WiFi at home since I tried with two different networks as well, and I've restarted my system twice to ensure that I haven't permanently turned off some wlan0 mode or feature. I assume that the router may be running as a WiFi hub or something else that doesn't broadcast TCP data, but I'm most likely wrong.

Is there any obvious reasons why I only see a broadcast traffic?